# How to insert a Clob into a Oracle table with Slick 3 and Oracle 12?

Tags: oracle, scala, slick, slick-3.0

- We have a table with a CLOB column (to save JSON data)
- As we understand (from the docs) slick support LOB types (http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/schemas.html)
- We are able to query the table succesfuly. Including the CLOB column.
- We are *not* able to insert a register with a Clob. We are converting a String to java.sql.Clob with:

  ```
  private java.sql.Clob stringToClob(String source)
  {
      try
      {
          return new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialClob(source.toCharArray());
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          log.error("Could not convert string to a CLOB",e);
          return null;
      }
  }
  ```

but in the end the exception from slick is the following:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialClob cannot be cast to oracle.sql.CLOB
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally found a workaround as follows:

According to the `column` definition in slick

```
def column[C](n: String, options: ColumnOption[C]*)(implicit tt: TypedType[C]): Rep[C]
```

You can specify how the column is going to be translated between the driver and your code. If you want to use the out-of-the-box translations fine but for Oracle the translation for the `CLOB` type doesn't seem to work properly.

What we did was to define the column as a `String` but letting Slick to handle the translation with our custom code. The column definiton is the following:

```
def myClobColumn = column[String]( "CLOBCOLUMN" )( new StringJdbcType )
```

asd

Being `StringJdbcType` our custom code to solve the translation between our `String` to be inserted (up to 65535 bytes) and an Oracle `CLOB`.

The code for `StringJdbcType` is as follows:

```
class StringJdbcType extends driver.DriverJdbcType[String] {
  def sqlType = java.sql.Types.VARCHAR
  // Here's the solution
  def setValue( v: String, p: PreparedStatement, idx: Int ) = {
    val conn = p.getConnection
    val clob = conn.createClob()
    clob.setString( 1, v )
    p.setClob( idx, clob )
  }
  def getValue( r: ResultSet, idx: Int ) = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream( r.getAsciiStream( "DSPOLIZARIESGO" ) )( Codec.ISO8859 ).getLines().mkString
  def updateValue( v: String, r: ResultSet, idx: Int ) = r.updateString( idx, v )
  override def hasLiteralForm = false
}
```

The `setValue` function was our salvation because we could build an Oracle `CLOB` with the already instantiated `PreparedStatement` and the String comming from our domain. In our implementation we only had to do the plumbing and dirty work for the Oracle CLOB.

In sum, the extension point offered by Slick in `driver.DriverJdbcType[A]` was what we actually used to make the thing work.

Comment: Hi juanpavergara, same implementation but we´re having OOMI issues when the column clob value is really big.
This is the column definition into the table class:
def clobColumn = column[String]( "CLOBCOLUMN", O.Length( 50000 ) )( new StringJdbcType )
The fact is that we are wondering if we could set the length of the BufferedSource where we are building it.

Answer (score 0):

These are some improvements related to the solution: close resources and stream inspection

```
  class BigStringJdbcType
    extends profile.DriverJdbcType[String] {

    def sqlType: Int = java.sql.Types.VARCHAR

    def setValue(v: String, p: PreparedStatement, idx: Int): Unit = {
      val connection = p.getConnection
      val clob = connection.createClob()
      try {
        clob.setString(1, v)
        p.setClob(idx, clob)
      } finally {
        clob.free()
      }
    }

    def getValue(r: ResultSet, idx: Int): String = {
      val asciiStream = r.getAsciiStream(idx)
      try {
        val (bufferEmpty, encoding) = getInputStreamStatus(asciiStream)

        if (bufferEmpty) {
          convertInputStreamToString(asciiStream, encoding)
        } else ""

      } finally {
        asciiStream.close()
      }
    }

    def updateValue(v: String, r: ResultSet, idx: Int): Unit =
      r.updateString(idx, v)

    override def hasLiteralForm: Boolean = false
  }
```

Some utilities to complement the solution

```
  def getInputStreamStatus(stream: InputStream): (Boolean, String) = {
    val reader = new InputStreamReader(stream)
    try {
      val bufferEmpty = reader.ready()
      val encoding = reader.getEncoding
      bufferEmpty -> encoding

    } finally {
      reader.close()
    }
  }

  def convertInputStreamToString(
    stream: InputStream,
    encoding: String
  ): String = {
    scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(stream)(encoding).getLines().mkString
  }
```